# How to get rows with Maximum id with condition of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, max

i have a table similar this

```
id-value-RowInid
1-xy-1
1-xx-2
1-xz-3
2-xx-1
2-xr-2
3-xq-1
4-xa-1
4-xc-2
...
```

i need a function for this table with similar output to get maximum of RowInid in separated id group

```
1-xz-3
2-xr-2
3-xq-1
4-xc-2
...
```

Comment: yes,  value field must be in output and is different in rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need for group by or max at all

```
select id, value, rowinid from
( select *, row_number() over (partition by id, order by rowinid desc) rn from yourtable ) v
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You just need to use `MAX(RowInid)` with `GROUP BY Id, value`</strike>

```
SELECT ID, VALUE, MAX(RowInid) FROM myTable GROUP BY ID, VALUE
```

**EDIT:**
As you updated your question, you can get `value` field using sub-query like this:

```
SELECT ID, VALUE, RowInid
FROM myTable t1 WHERE RowInid = 
(
    SELECT MAX(RowInid) FROM myTable WHERE id = t1.id GROUP BY id
)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

You can also achieve this using `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT t2.ID, VALUE, t2.RowInid FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(RowInid) AS RowIniD FROM myTable GROUP BY ID
) AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.RowInid = t2.RowInid
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8e74/8)

See more about [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [`MAX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) in SQL Server.

Comment: value field must be in your output

Comment: @jozi Ok. updated the answer. And How do you decide `value = xz` for `id = 1` and `value = xr` for `id = 2`?

Comment: value field is string for example names and we have not max in value field

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

Use Sub Query to get Id, Value and Max RowInid,

```
  SELECT m1.[Id],m1.Value, m1.RowInid
  FROM [Practice].[dbo].[myTable] m1 WHERE RowInid = (SELECT MAX(m2.RowInid) FROM [Practice].[dbo].[myTable] m2 WHERE M1.Id = m2.Id GROUP BY Id)
```

above query return result like:
4-xx-2
3-xx-1
2-xx-2
1-xx-3

To Ascending this use,

```
SELECT  m1.[id],m1.Value, m1.RowInid
FROM [Practice].[dbo].[myTable] m1 WHERE m1.RowInid = (SELECT MAX(m2.RowInid) FROM [Practice].[dbo].[myTable] m2 WHERE M2.id = m1.id GROUP BY id)  ORDER BY m1.id ASC
```